# How to redirect C/C++ printf() messages to windows phone logging system

Tags: c++, c, windows-phone-7, logging

I want to compile a C/C++ macro which allows me to log debug messages on many different platforms. My code is good for Android, iPhone, Win32 and I want to add support to WindowsPhone.

How do I do it (be able to write ascii messages to log file/console)?

I am new to the WindowsPhone platform so if there are few different logging systems please advice to me which one to use.

My code is attached below:

```
#if (WIN_PC_OS)
  // In windows EXE's, DLL's and Lib's allow logging
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_INFO(...)   fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_WARN(...)   fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_ERR_(...)   fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#elif (ANDR_OS)
  // Redirect log messages to android log.
  #include <android/log.h>
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_INFO(...)   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO    ,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_WARN(...)   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN    ,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_ERR_(...)   __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR   ,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#elif (APPLE_OS)
  // Redirect log messages to iPhone log. Like NSLog(@__VA_ARGS__);
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_INFO(...)   fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)     
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_WARN(...)   fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
  #define MY_SYSTEM_LOG_ERR_(...)   fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
#else
  // Windows phone supported yet!!!!
#endif
```

Comment: Which is it, C or C++?

Comment: I don't care which language. I will compile it with C++ compiler. printf() is C function but C++ compiler accepts it.

Comment: @Casey, I get the whole effort to decouple C and C++ - even though I find it annoying more often than not - but sometimes it just doesn't matter.  Certain aspects of C are always going to be part of C++.

Comment: @DanielHsH are you really targeting windows phone 7? That's considered obsolete by MS... if you're targeting windows phone 8 you probably want to be using the tools in the [`Windows::Foundation::Diagnostics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.foundation.diagnostics.aspx) namespace for logging, as there is no guarantee `stderr` will go where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone Runtime has the usual `stderr` and `stdout` descriptors that you can use similarly to the `WIN_PC_OS` case that you've shown in the snippet in the question. In fact you can just combine the two cases.

But you’ve indicated both C and C++ as tags for the question, so note that if you wish to provide a separate macro for C++ and use `std::cerr` with `std::endl`, as in,

```
std::cerr << "INFO my info log message" << std::endl;
```

will flush the output buffer, while with C consider whether you need to `fflush(stderr)` after you `fprintf(stderr)`.